# Trying to deploy app in heroku but it gets stuck due to an infinite loop with my build script?

Tags: heroku, deployment, package.json

[image]

When I am trying to deploy my application, the above ^^^ just keeps repeating and the deployment never finishes.

Here are the scripts of my package.json in my backend: backend/package.json

```
"scripts": {
    "start-server": "node server.js",
    "start": "concurrently --kill-others-on-fail \"npm run server\" \"npm run client\"",
    "server": "nodemon server.js",
    "client": "cd frontend && npm start",
    "build": "cd frontend/ && npm install && npm run build"
  },
```

Here are the scripts of the package.json in my frontend code

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "PORT=8888 react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
```

Any help would be much apprieciated, this is my first time trying to deploy an application so to be honest, I'm a bit lost.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why, but I actually solved this issue once i removed the .git file in my backend folder and simply git init again.